# Angularjs ng-repeat object in object error: duplicates in repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, duplicates, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple iteration with `ng-repeat` over my nested object which looks something like this

```
$scope.data = {
  name: "",
  id: "",
  nestedObj: {
     prop1: "string",
     prop2: false,
     prop3: ""
  }
};
```

In my view I try it like this

```html
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.nestedObj">
 {{key}} : {{value}}
</div>
```

...but I constantly get following console error:

`Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: (key, value) in data.type key: string`

Am I missing out something or what am I doing wrong?

## UPDATE!

So after the answer from [Sajeetharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749403/sajeetharan) and the comment from [Slava Utesinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5630778/slava-utesinov) I've set up a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SScZVjfn9JPpr637vsJ4) to give it a try. Surprisingly the answer is, that you obviously can't iterate over an object if it has more than one "empty" key (empty string as value) inside of it.

## UPDATE 2

Also it seems, that you can't use the same string value twice ... god I love Angular :)

## Finale UPDATE

As [Sajeetharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749403/sajeetharan) and [Slava Utesinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5630778/slava-utesinov) mentioned, `track by $index` solved it for me

Comment: You have two properties with same `prop2` name.

Comment: My bad - thank you, I updated the question. But this isn't the problem

Comment: You should reproduce your error via plunker. May be `nestedObj` is array?

Comment: So modify to this `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.nestedObj track by $index"`

Comment: I'm going to give it a try and update my question with the result!

Comment: You were right [Slava Utesinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5630778/slava-utesinov), `track by $index` solved the duplicate error for me :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing bracket in your object.

Try this:

```
$scope.data = {
  name: "",
  id: "",
  nestedObj: {
     prop1: "string",
     prop2: false,
     prop2: ""
  } 
};
```